# "Storyboard.storyboard" could not be opened

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

> The document "Storyboard.storyboard" could not be opened. Could not
>   read archive.
>
> Please use a newer version of Xcode. Consider changing the document's
>   Development Target to preserve compatibility.

Can't we run it on xcode 4.2 by making some changes in settings.

Answer (score 26):

Open storyboard file as source code, then change the version at the beginning from 2.0 to 1.0. Open it this time as storyboard file and voila :)

got it from: http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2012/09/17/how-to-open-a-storyboard-created-with-xcode-4-3-or-4-4-with-xcode-4-2-workaround/

Comment: Or change it from `3.0` to `2.0` in the case you have opened it with Xcode 5 before.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. I tried the Xcode 5 Preview and then could't reopen stroryboard with Xcode 4

Answer (score 1):

Select 'Storyboard.storyboard' in the project navigator. Go to the utilities area and open File Inspector. In the Document versioning section, change  the 'Development' to Xcode 4.2