# Interface Builder could not open the document "MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard" because it does not exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After an awfull mistake, I deleted most of the files in my project i succesfully managed to get them all back but I have encounterd ALOT of errors now, e.g. "Interface Builder could not open the document "MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard" because it does not exist." is one of them, I have checked the file in finder and its there, when I press the file in project navigator I can see the storyboard I created but when I run the project I keep get that error...

My project navigator looks like this: http://screencast.com/t/dNVioFQg9
And my info.plist doesnt work for some reason..: http://screencast.com/t/JyqV32Ugt
and these are my errors: http://screencast.com/t/GJHfGGwQgn0Y

I also followed the solutions in this thread but nothing helped...["Storyboard.storyboard" could not be opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030314/storyboard-storyboard-could-not-be-opened/19258323#19258323)
and
[Interface Builder could not open the document ".storyboard" because it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860534/interface-builder-could-not-open-the-document-storyboard-because-it-does-not)

Please someone help me!

Comment: Sounds like you don't have all the files back and haven't added some of them to the app target? What did you do and how did you restore? Are you not using version control?

Comment: when I look in my finder I can see all the files that are in the project manager, how do I add them to the app target? doesnt I need access to the info.plist for that(which I cant even access :S)?

I deleted most of the files by mistake and then restored them from trash(draged them from trash to the project map in finder and then draged them back to xcode) what is version control?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360887/using-version-control-for-home-development

Comment: No i havent used a version control

Comment: You should start. I guess you don't have time machine running either. Did you delete the files from inside Xcode or Finder?

Comment: I hoped for the time machine aswell but dum as I am it was not enabled...I deleted the files inside from Xcode and chose put them in trash which it did..

Btw i got the info.plist to work so I am not able to enter the "info" tab BUT I still get an error that tells me my [projectname]-info.plist couldnt be opened because there is no such file..

Comment: It's kinda late now, but you should have started with `Put Back` in Finder from the Trash. Some of your files could be / sounds like they are in the wrong place / folders. You might want to create a new project and see where the files are so you can copy things back. Also look at the build settings and build phases to try to rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my issue!!!! For all you who encounter the same problem, delete file one file at the time and put it back to the project map and then xcode, keep do that with all of the files and dont forget to press the file within the project navigator after you draged the file in there.

Answer (score 0):

How i solved this very same issue:

- go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
- delete the folder called ("yourApp's Name"-some xcode generated string)
- build again.

Hope it will help some one.